# source of $_GET['code'] to get refresh token for youtube api credentials

Tags: php, api, curl, get, refresh

I am learner of php, I have got to work with youtube api credentials after all my attempts to generate refresh token, I found this code but I can't get where does the `$code` comes from.

Please can any one help me out in finding where does this `$_GET['code']` comes from in the below code,this is my first question in stack-overflow. please kindly ignore if there are any mistakes.

```
 if(isset($_GET['code'])) {

     $code = $_GET['code'];

    $url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';

    $params = array(
        "code" => $code,

        "client_id" => "client_id",
        "client_secret" => "client_secret",
        "redirect_uri" => "redirect_uri",
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code"
    );
    $curl = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $authObj = json_decode($json_response);

    "access_token: " . $authObj->access_token;
    "token_type: " . $authObj->token_type;
    "expires_in: " . $authObj->expires_in;
    "refresh_token: " . $authObj->refresh_token;

 }
```

Comment: `$_GET` means it's a URL parameter, i.e. `http://localhost/page.php?code=12345`. There's [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Comment: accept my answer if it helped

Answer (score 2):

Usually your url would be

```
    http://example.com/yourpage.php?code=abbcd
```

this type of url is called a query string   in this querysting has 2 variables
notice the ?after that you just asign you data a variable like above
you can add more data by using & eg. `&secondcode=abcasdda`
so your new url would be

```
 http://example.com/yourpage.php?code=abbcd&secondcode=abcasdda
```

so

```
     $code = $_GET['code'];

        echo $code  

///OUTPUT  :  abbcd
```

this is how you would fetch the variable

Comment: on a side note if this is sensitive data i would advice encrypting it or using POST if possible

Comment: if it was sensitive data, youd never use `GET` in the first place.